# Problem associated with transferring data from pdf tables to csv

Tags: python, csv, pdf, pypdf

I have a large PDF file of 100 pages, almost entirely consisting of tables. Here he is:
[file](https://iss.moex.com/file/MarketT_061223.pdf)
I need to extract data from this table and transfer it to Excel, but for convenience, I first need to write this data into a csv file.

I've used python and various libraries, from like pypdf2 and camelot, to trying to install slicemypdf (failed).
pypdf2 did the best job with respect to time/result, but it has problems with outputting empty cells and numbers with separate writing (1,000 = 1.000, but the split() method does not separate them correctly).
I will be glad for any help, I have been working on this project for a huge number of days and nights.
P.s. I'm a newbie, I ask for as detailed an explanation as possible

Answer (score -1):

Certainly! Extracting data from tables in PDF files can be a challenging task, and there are different approaches to achieve this. Since you mentioned that you've tried pypdf2 and camelot, I'll guide you through an alternative approach using the `tabula-py` library, which is built on top of Apache PDFBox.

Here are the steps you can follow:

#### Step 1: Install the required libraries

Make sure you have the necessary libraries installed. You can install them using the following commands:

```bash
pip install tabula-py pandas
```

#### Step 2: Extract tables from PDF using `tabula-py`

```py
import tabula

# Replace 'your_file_path.pdf' with the actual path to your PDF file
file_path = 'your_file_path.pdf'

# Use tabula to extract tables from the PDF
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file_path, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)

# 'tables' now contains a list of DataFrames, where each DataFrame corresponds to a table on a page
```

#### Step 3: Clean and structure the data

Since tables may have varying structures, you'll need to inspect the extracted tables and decide how to structure the data. You can use the pandas library to work with DataFrames.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index=True)

# Display the DataFrame to inspect the structure
print(df)
```

#### Step 4: Save the DataFrame to a CSV file

```py
# Replace 'output_file.csv' with the desired output file path
output_file = 'output_file.csv'

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)
```

#### Note:

1. **Empty Cells:** You might need to handle empty cells separately based on your specific requirements. Pandas may represent empty cells as NaN (Not a Number).
2. **Numeric Formatting:** Pandas typically handles numeric formatting well, but you can use the `float_format` parameter in the `to_csv` method to customize it further if needed.
3. **Customizing Output:** Depending on the structure of your tables, you may need to clean and structure the data further. You can use pandas functions to manipulate the DataFrame as needed.

Feel free to adapt the code based on your specific PDF file and table structures. If you encounter any issues or have specific requirements, please provide more details, and I'll be happy to assist further.

Comment: I tested tabula-py one of the first, I didn’t like its result at all, the number of real columns does not correspond to the number of columns that tabula-py outputs